# How to import the HTML type?

Tags: go

The [`html/template` documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#hdr-Typed_Strings) mentions an `HTML` type:

> Types HTML, JS, URL, and others from content.go can carry safe content
>   that is exempted from escaping.

How can I import and use it?

I have tried the following code, which throws an "undefined: HTML" error ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hrrrp8d4jQ)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(HTML(`<strong>Hi</strong>`))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope the types with the package name:

package main

```
import (
  "fmt"
  "html/template"
)

func main() {
   fmt.Println(template.HTML(`<strong>Hi</strong>`))
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/ij2WIP4mdX)

Comment: That works! Now isn't the documentation is a bit misleading? It shows code like this: `tmpl.Execute(out, HTML(\`<b>World</b>\`))`.

Comment: Documentation is written in the context of the package, you do not need the full qualifier when using `HTML` from the `html/template` package itself.